# eclipse c++ exclude multiple files from build at once?

Tags: c++, eclipse, build

Instead of right clicking each one individually, ticking 'exclude from build', etc
And how to include them back en masse ?

Thanks

Comment: check out makefiles, and have a line for whatever it is you want individually compiled. Not sure what IDE youre using, sorry I couldnt be more help. edit, shit I see it now, eclipse. sorry, no idea =( but still, makefile!

Answer (score 11):

Highlight one of your file's by left clicking it.  Then, to select multiple files, hold down shift or control then left click on another file. Shift will select all files between what you selected.  Control will add just the one.  Then, let go of shift (or control), then right click one of the selected files, then chose "Resource Configurations > Exclude from build...".  It will exclude them all.  Similarly, repeat the step to add them back.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new folder inside Eclipse (let's name it *excluded*). Right-click on *excluded* and  use `Resource Configuration->Exclude From Build...`, check which builds you want it excluded from and dismiss the dialog. Now you can disable files by selecting a group of files and dragging them to this folder. Include them back in the build by dragging them from *excluded* back to their original location.  **Note** that once marked as excluded the folder appears near the bottom with a new icon with a slash through it.